# stacking function for values in R

Tags: r, stack

I am in the process of creating a new column with values from different datasets. Right Now I am at the point where I added all values at the right place in the dataset, but it is still spread over different columns. This has to become one column.

I want [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6ydZ.jpg) (picture is easier than words imo).

[image]

So far I used `pull` to get the values from the columns
then I used `cbind` to knit them all together , so basically I have the same structure as starting out, only now with only the values that need to go in one row.

My thought for the next step was to `stack` all the variables, then remove all the NA's (`na.omit` or `drop_na`) and then create a new column with `mutate` something like `df <- mutate(df, VRM = valueswithoutNA $ VRMvalues)`

However, I get stuck at the `stack`, because I get an error:

> arguments imply differing number of rows: 511370, 0

Tips for getting around this error or to solve my problem in a different way?

edit:
toy-example

```
dfcol1 <- c("St1", "St2", "St3", "St4", "St5", "St6",
                              "St7", "St8", "St9", "St10", "St11")
dfcol2 <- c("S1", "S2", "S3", "t4", "S5", "S6",
            "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10", "S11")

df_with_new_column <- cbind(dfcol1, dfcol2)

aa <- c(1,2,3, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
bb <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
cc <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,NA,NA)
dd <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,2)

abcd <- cbind(aa,bb,cc,dd)
```

Comment: I see your logic but how do you want to merge these values? Are they numbers you want to add? text you want to merge together?

Comment: What are the values you do not want? All NAs or something else? This would be easier for us with a toy example of your matrix/dataframe/tibble as input and what you want as output

Comment: @boski The values I want to add together in one column are all numbers.

Comment: @Henry The only values I do not want are NA. I will try making a toy-example.

Comment: @Cath, I think you are right, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Package `dplyr` as a function `coalesce` perfect for this problem.

```
library(dplyr)

m <- matrix(NA, 4, 3)
diag(m) <- 1:3
m[4, 3] <- 4
m

Reduce(coalesce, as.data.frame(m))
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

WIth the data in the question, but `df_with_new_column` created as an actual data.frame, it becomes:

```
df_with_new_column <- data.frame(dfcol1, dfcol2)

df_with_new_column$newcol <- Reduce(coalesce, as.data.frame(abcd))

df_with_new_column
#   dfcol1 dfcol2 newcol
#1     St1     S1      1
#2     St2     S2      2
#3     St3     S3      3
#4     St4     t4      1
#5     St5     S5      2
#6     St6     S6      3
#7     St7     S7      1
#8     St8     S8      2
#9     St9     S9      3
#10   St10    S10      1
#11   St11    S11      2
```